# From PNG+PGW+PRJ map format to MBTILES

Tags: mbtiles

I'm new (on Windows) and I'm trying to convert maps from PNG + PGW + PRJ format in a map format compatible with OrumMaps. I saw that GDAL can convert to MBTILES but I don't understand if it support PRJ file format.

How can I convert this format with GDAL?

The PRJ has format like this:

`PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

I have already installed OSGeo4W to get GDAL on Windows.

Comment: Read first https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html and https://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html.

Comment: Looking on the web, I had found those pages but looking for the term "prj" and not having found it I thought it could not be used. OK, I start reading

Comment: If `gdalinfo your.png` reports the extents and coordinate system of your image right you will have no problem. Have you tried?

Comment: I tried to launch the command you said, what do you think about?
[Clic here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aii5anhGIaef62lQXUy7lVEAMv1v)

Comment: GDAL finds the coordinates from the .pgw file but is does not read the coordinate system from .prj. System seems to be EPSG:32632 https://epsg.io/32632. Your command should look like `gdal_translate -of MBTiles -s_srs epsg:32632 input.png output.mbtiles`.

Comment: The coordinate system is right, but the line code generates an error: `ERROR 6: Unknown option name -s_srs` maybe is`-a_srs epsg:32632`?

Comment: Sorry, you are right that -s_srs is missing from gdal_translate. -a_srs is not quite right but you could do it in two steps. `gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs epsg:32632 input.png temporary.vrt`and then `gdal_translate -of MBTiles temporary.vrt output.mbtiles`. Another option is to use gdalwarp `gdalwarp -of MBTiles -s_srs epsg:32632 input.png output.mbtiles`. Both commands untested but they should be close to correct.

Comment: The first method works, the second returns an error: `ERROR 6: Only EPSG:3857 supported on MBTiles dataset`.

Comment: Then add `-t_srs epsg:3857` into gdalwarp command. I was thinking that perhaps gdalwarp knows to do that automatically because epsg:3857 is the only supported srs.

Comment: I'm left with a doubt: why this line seems to work correctly but is not right? `gdal_translate -of MBTiles -a_srs epsg:32632 input.png output.mbtiles`

Comment: If you read the docs `-a_srs srs_def: Override the projection for the output file.` If you used for example GeoTIFF as an outputformat what would happen is "convert my png that is in epsg:32632 into geotiff without reprojecting data, but claim that the result is in epsg:3857" and the result is wrong. MBTiles is a special because the format supports only epsg:3857 and gdal_translate is also reprojecting image data when  needed. It is not possible to assign epsg:32632 into MBTiles because that is not supported but I don't know what MBTiles driver does in this case.